# Translating a formula into recursion

Tags: formula

[See picture here](http://img201.imageshack.us/img201/7408/14210487.jpg)

Hello,
I need to convert the formula above to code (Java or C#)
I did a lot of tries without success.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Please provide some examples of what you have tried.  Also, please try to display the formula directly in the text of the question: SO is a reference system; it can't search images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your answer in Java:

```
public static int f(int n) {
    if(n == 0)
        return 1;
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        sum += f(i) * f(n - 1 - i);
    return sum;
}
```

Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Below code is in php, in java or c# would have same logic
assuming f(x) return x+1, for n=3, sum would be 10

```
<?php
function fun($x)
{
  echo $x+1;
  return $x+1;
}

$n=3;
$sum=0;

if($n>0)
{
  $i = $n-1;
  while($i>=0)
  {
    $sum = $sum +(fun($i) * fun($n-1-$i));
    $i= $i-1;
  }
}
else if($n=0)
{
   $sum = 1;
}
echo $sum;
?>
```